# A Knight's Tour

Tags: chess, graph-theory, knight-moves

A lonely chess knight stands on a cell somewhere in the first row of a 3x13 board, and elsewhere there is a castle.

The knight takes a tour of all the remaining 37 cells of the board, missing just the cell where the castle stands.

Where is the castle?

Comment: How long is the first row?

Comment: @msh210 13 cells

Comment: Does the tour start from where the knight is, thus making 38 squares, and is it open or closed?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Yes, starts where it is and it is open.

Comment: Does the final (and initial) cell of the knight have to be _not_ knight-adjacent to the castle?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the corner squares are black, the standard parity argument shows that the castle must be on a black square. However, a Mathematica two-liner shows it could be on **any** black square and there would still be a tour of the other 38 squares starting from a first-row square:
>  `H = KnightTourGraph[13, 3]; GraphicsGrid[Table[{HighlightGraph[H, PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[VertexDelete[H, n]]], GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]}, {n, 1, 39, 2}]]`
>  [image]
>  In the above the boards have been rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise; note that every tour starts from the rightmost square of row 1 (on the unrotated board; top-left corner of the rotated one) except the last one (where the removed square is the rightmost/top-left square itself).